# Unable to create rds instance using cloud formation?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, database, cloud, amazon-cloudformation

Iam trying to create an rds mysql instance using cloud formation.But when iam creating the stack iam getting rollback.Under events the error for creating rds instance is "Encountered unsupported property Description".Please anyone help.Iam new to cloud formation.

```
Resources:
 mydbsubgrp:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
        DBSubnetGroupDescription: mydbsubnet
        DBSubnetGroupName: mydbsub
        SubnetIds: 
            - subnet-8ba626ec
            - subnet-8cb13ea2
        Tags:
            - Key: "Name"
              Value: "wpdb" 



 myrds:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
        Description: rds instace for wordpress
        Engine: MySQL
        EngineVersion: 5.6.13
        AllocatedStorage: 100
        BackupRetentionPeriod: 7
        DBInstanceIdentifier: mydbinstance
        DBName: wordpress
        DBInstanceClass: t2.micro
        DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref mydbsubgrp
        MasterUsername: redhat1234
        MasterUserPassword: redhat1234
        PubliclyAccessible: true

Outputs:
    rdsdetails:
        Description: rds endpoint
        Value: !GetAtt myrds.Endpoint.Address
```

Comment: The message appears to be trying to say `Encountered unsupported property: 'Description'`.  Does an AWS::RDS::DBInstance support a property called `Description`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message tells you what's the problem: *Encountered unsupported property **Description***

There is no `Description` property for `AWS::RDS::DBInstance`. See **[here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html)** for all the properties available.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thx dude..it helped